# Replicate A column with number of B column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame *d.tbl*.

```
A      B
1000   20
2000   40
```

I would like to create a vector `x`, which will be `c(1000...1000, 2000...2000)` that *1000* repeat *20* times and *2000* repeats *40* times.
Is there any way to approach this result?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `rep()` and column `A` as values to repeat and column `B` as times to repeat.

```
rep(d.tbl$A,d.tbl$B)
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot there's a function `rep()`!